# How to create a Startup Application in JavaME

Tags: java-me

How to create a Startup Application in JavaME.the Program will starts while the boot up of the Mobile

Answer (score 1):

For nokia add jad attribute.

> Nokia-MIDlet-auto-start: yes

possible values are yes, no and once.

on SE devices JP7onwards you can use 
pushregistry entry

> MIDlet-Push-1: autostart://:,,*

static and dynamic both will work

in blackberry go project properties ->application tab-> check option "Auto-run on startup"

don't know about other devices like motorola.

Comment: It's a good answer, as good as you will get on J2ME, but these are unlikely to work across all handsets unless apps are signed.

Comment: the Nokia-Midlet-start property is not work in nokia n97 mobile